# Google Auth for external site in ASP.NET VB/JQuery - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, google-authentication

I'm working on a project where I usually create my sites as an Intranet site so security wasn't too great a concern, but I'm working on an ASP.NET VB site using Google Auth to allow only our users access to it (or anyone within our group of companies).  Firstly; I've managed to successfully implement the login system, so it will allow you to login, but how do I go about creating a "not logged in" page that it defaults to if the user isn't logged in (I've been experimenting with `auth2.isSignedIn.get()` to get that result, however I'm concerned that it's in the wide open, it's susceptible to hack attempts.  Is using the JQuery/Javascript method safe enough?

I'm also fairly new with ASP.NET VB (24 hours actually) so please be gentle, I've come from Classic ASP to this behemoth!

To show what I have working in a basic form ... here is my code:

```
window.onLoadCallback = function () {
         gapi.load('auth2', function () {
             gapi.auth2.init({
                 client_id: 'myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com',
             }).then(function () {
                 auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                 if (!auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
                     console.log("Not logged in...");
                 } else {
                     console.log("Should be logged in...");
                 }
             });
         });
     };
```

Would that be classed as secure enough or is there a better, safer way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You could simply fire up a project wizard for a WebApplication with thirdparty signin and enable the Google settings in the App_Start\Startup.auth.cs/vb. The scaffolded projects have full support for OWIN login with very little work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll work down that route, I think I need a WebApp to accomplish what I'm trying to do